# AppCompat Toolbar elevation missing (with RecyclerView) despite setting properties

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-toolbar

For some reason, my `Toolbar` won't cast a shadow for elevation. I even tried in Java but it's still not working.

Any ideas on why this isn't performing as expected? 
My app doesn't support pre-Lollipop (minimum API is 24).

**activity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/masterToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/master_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**toolbar XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mytoolbar_textlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytoolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**activity class**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Boolean mCurrentValue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.md);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        setContentView(R.layout.md);

        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Boolean mNewValue = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("my_preference", false);

        if (mCurrentValue != mNewValue) {
            recreate();
        }

        // ... do other stuff here
        Resources r = getBaseContext().getResources();
        int fourDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, r.getDisplayMetrics());

        final String toolbarColour = "#EE7C0E";

        Toolbar mMasterToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mMasterToolbar);
        mMasterToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(toolbarColour));
        mMasterToolbar.setElevation(fourDp);
        mMasterToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });


        final TextView mTitle = this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_1line_title);
        mTitle.setText(getString(R.string.london_overground));

        FragmentMain newFragment = new FragmentMain();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `android:background` in your `Toolbar`.

**Example:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
```

**Note:** In order to apply elevation to any view, it needs to have a background.

---

**EDIT:**
Since your app has a min SDK 24 you can use the `translationZ` attribute.

Comment: Remove the LinearLayout that is encapsulating your `Toolbar`, and add a background to it.

Comment: My bacground already had a background set programmatically, hence this doesn't work either

Comment: Are you sure? There is no reference to a background in the code you posted. Also, this line `Toolbar mMasterToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_1line);` points to none of the views in your activity layout.

Comment: Just fixed typos in my code. Yes I am sure. This is such a weird one.

Comment: Surprisingly that option does. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that this fixes your issue. Please mark this answer has it correct one so it can helper others :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the linear layout and width and height attributes in your activity xml. You only need the include tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/master_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your Toolbar xml, try app:elevation since you're using the supportActionBar support library.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
app:elevation="4dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mytoolbar_textlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytoolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I think this could be the right answer. The LinearLayout wrapping the Toolbar probably crops the shadow, since shadows are drawn by default _outside_ the bounds of the view.

Comment: For some reason, this still doesn't solve the issue. That's strange.

Comment: Also, move all of the code to create the toolbar from onStart to onCreate. And remove the duplicate setContentView in onStart. You only need that once. And remove setting all the colors/elevations to the toolbar programmatically. You should only have to set those once in the xml file.